# Docker python app can't find `PATH_INFO` env variable

Tags: python, docker, nginx

I'm trying to run python backend using Docker, however app can't find `PATH_INFO` environment variable. Though on another machine it works well, difference is OS version: previous is `ubuntu 21.04` and current is `ubuntu 22.04`

The error is caused by this piece of code:

```
path = environ.get("PATH_INFO", "/").lower()
```

here environ is a dict containing all env variables

App is running using `docker-compose` which creates contianer, where `ENTRYPOINT` includes `docker_entry` file:

```
import bjoern
from index import app
bjoern.run(app, '0.0.0.0', 80)
```

where `app` is

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler().run(app)
```

Comment: Is `PATH_INFO` exists on your current os? check it by cmd: `printenv | grep PATH_INFO`

Comment: @Whoiskp no, there is no such variable. Do I need to add it to my `.bashrc`? Though app is running inside Docker container. So can you tell what value should I set to it?

Comment: If the env var `PATH_INFO` is not found, this code will default to using `/`.  This should not, in itself, cause an error.  What actual error are you getting?

Comment: _Though on another machine it works well_ Then the environment on the other machine must have that variable, and the environment on your current machine does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PATH_INFO` must be set during your script execution, it is not a default variable available on the OS. You likely can try printing out all the env variables before starting your script or inside it.

```
# bash
env

# python
import os
print(os.environ)
```

edit: you might be assuming nginx sets `PATH_INFO` for your script, like it does for PHP FPM. It is not.

Comment: Yes, I assumed that it's created automatically by nginx. Do you know what value should it have?

Comment: depends on the engine you are using to run your python, uwsig or gunicorn would have different

Comment: It uses `wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler().run(app)` inside Docker container. Strange think is that I've run `printenv | grep PATH_INFO` on the server and inside running Docker container - in both cases there was no such variable, though backend runs fine

Comment: you need to extend the question with how you start your app, it seems you are using something different from the example on https://docs.python.org/3/library/wsgiref.html

Comment: It was an error in `vs code` debugger config - wrong entry point file. That lead to situation when app method was invoked at incorrect moment. And, as it turned out, `PATH_INFO` is set on API call